# Restoring Windows boot entry on GRUB

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, grub, bcd

I made a lot of mistakes lately with my systems, and now I have an issue.
After installing fedora 20, I tried to resize my windows 7 partition, and generated an error with the actual size of the partition vs the size the boot sector said it had.
Trying to fix that, I deleted the MBR as well as the BCD with the windows repair command line. And then, I could not enter the recovery mode ever again.
Also, I couldn't mount the NTFS partition on my fedora system.

I ran ntfsfix in fedora and now I can mount the NTFS partition, however i cannot add it to GRUB.

I ran bootinfoscript and these are the results:

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
    location.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /BOOTMGR /BOOT/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe /ubuntu/winboot/wubildr 
                       /ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub2/grub.cfg

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       LVM2_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

fedora-swap': __________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

fedora-root': __________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
```

MY Windows 7 partition is in /dev/sda3 but note that it says that there are no errors.

However, at the end of the results of bootinfoscript there is:

```
=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

hexdump: sda3/pagefile.sys: Input/output error
hexdump: sda3/pagefile.sys: Input/output error
hexdump: sda3/pagefile.sys: Input/output error
cat: /tmp/BootInfo-4U0PN36P/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/BootInfo-4U0PN36P/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
hexdump: /dev/mapper/fedora-swap': No such file or directory
hexdump: stdin: Bad file descriptor
hexdump: /dev/mapper/fedora-swap': No such file or directory
hexdump: all input file arguments failed
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
hexdump: /dev/mapper/fedora-root': No such file or directory
hexdump: stdin: Bad file descriptor
hexdump: /dev/mapper/fedora-root': No such file or directory
hexdump: all input file arguments failed
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

I don't know of the first 3 lines have something to do with it.

On sda1 i have the Acer recovery system (to go back to factory settings, something i don't want) and in sda2 there is the /boot partition of windows.

I also tried the [solution here](http://boringtalk.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/solving-the-problem-of-missing-windows-7-entry-in-grub2-on-fedora-18/) changing *set root=(hd0,1)* with *set root=(hd0,2)* and  *set root=(hd0,3)* but I had no success.

Any ideas on how can I boot my windows 7 system?

Thanks a lot!!!